# How can I use functions in file paths?

Tags: string-manipulation, files-and-directories

I'm very new to *Mathematica* and I'm trying to write into a file. I want to have a function in my file path. For Example:

```
s = OpenWrite["/Users/Home/Desktop/file[i].doc"]
```

Obviously in this format it will read it as it exactly appears above. How can I get it to open the file with the result for `file[i]`?

i.e. If `file[i] = 1` 
then the program will compute:

```
s = OpenWrite["/Users/Home/Desktop/1.doc"]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just another way, with `Templates` so only for `V10+`:

The following can be done without `FileNameJoin` but it is a good habit to use it:

```
file[i] = 1;

TemplateApply @ FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Desktop", "<*file[i]*>.doc"}]
```

> ...Desktop\1.doc

`"<**>"` is `TemplateExpression`

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure this is a duplicate but to give you a quick answer here's a community wiki post:

Use [`ToString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToString.html) and [`StringJoin`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringJoin.html) to form your argument:

```
file[i] = 1;

"/Users/Home/Desktop/" <> ToString @ file[i] <> ".doc"
```

> ```
> "/Users/Home/Desktop/1.doc"
> ```

Also look at [`FileNameJoin`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FileNameJoin.html).

Answer (score 2):

At the risk of betraying how long I've been using *Mathematica*, the method I'm accustomed to uses `StringForm[]` (in conjunction with `ToString[]` since the output of that function, nonintuitively, is not a string):

```
file[i] = 1;

OpenWrite[ToString[StringForm["/Users/Home/Desktop/`1`.doc", file[i]]]]
```